# helm with if condition and its scope for the value set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to overwrite the user template with `.Values.userTemplate` if it exist. But I always get `$user` as `undefined` when the `.Vaues.userTemplate` exist. If i remove `if` condition and use `{{- $user := tpl .Values.userTemplate . -}}`, it gives right value. But inside `if` codition it is not setting the value for `$user`.

Is there anything was doing wrong? Was the scope of `$user` will be only retained inside the `if` condition? Was there a way to overwrite the `$user` if `.Values.userTemplate` exist.

```
    # values
    user: "default"
       # somewhere in other chart we define the  template
    userTemplate: '{{ include "username" . }}'

    # template
    {{- define "user" -}}
    {{- if .Values.userTemplate -}}
    {{- $user := tpl .Values.userTemplate . -}}
    {{- else -}}
    {{- $user := .Values.user -}}
    {{- end -}}
    {{- $user -}}

    # output of `{{ template "user" . }}` should be the value set in `{{ template "username" . }} in different chart. 

Tom
```

Comment: `userTempalte` is not `userTemplate` ;). Seems like a typo

Comment: Well the sample has typo which I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I use helm 2.10. 
I did a small test. If I understand correctly it is what you want:

values.yml:

```
user: "default"
userTemplate: '{{ include "userName" . }}'
otherName: "john"
```

_helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "userName" -}}
{{- .Values.otherName -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "user" -}}
{{- if .Values.userTemplate -}}
{{- tpl .Values.userTemplate . -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- .Values.user -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

test.yml:

```
name: {{ template "user" . }}
```

With a userTemplate, I got `john`, without userTemplate I got `default`.