# How to include default value with tpl function call

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm

I have top level chart and one of the subcharts. In subchart I want to use variables that defined in level chart, and if it is not found - use default value.

I have code like this in one of deployment definitions in my subchart

```
name: {{tpl .Values.global.my.GlobalValue .}}
```

where Values.global.my.GlobalValue - is parameter from top level chart.

Problem is when I try to install only subchart - I am failing, I need some defaults.

I tried to puth like below and it is not working

```
name: {{default defaultName tpl .Values.global.my.GlobalValue .}}
name: {{tpl .Values.global.my.GlobalValue . | defaultName}}
```

Could you please advise the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Using the default function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#using-the-default-function):

> One function frequently used in templates is the `default` function:
>   `default DEFAULT_VALUE GIVEN_VALUE`. This function allows you to specify
>   a default value inside of the template, in case the value is omitted.

You should use:

`name: {{ .Values.global.my.GlobalValue | default "defaultName" | quote }}`

Comment: There is an error now -  executing ".../statefulset.yaml" at <tpl>: wrong number of args for tpl: want 2 got 1

Comment: And without using tpl it gives - .../statefulset.yaml" at <.Values.global.my...>: can't evaluate field "my" in type interface {} I expected that if can't resolve - it takes default

Comment: Hi what about adding your first example with if else statement like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238636/11207414)